# on a way of copying code that involves "super" keyword for supporting inheritance

Tags: solidity, inheritance

I wonder the exact mechanism of copying code that involves "super" keyword for supporting inheritance in Solidity.

Below is an example code that elaborates my question.

```
contract C { 
    function test() public {  } 
}

contract B is C {
    function bbb() public {  }
    function test() public {
       bbb(); 
       super.test(); 
    }
} 

contract A is B {
}
```

If we deploy the contract `A` and calls the function `A.test()`, then the actual (and desirable) effect is a call sequence of `bbb()->C.test()` (where super is replaced with C).

However, literally following the below explanation on inheritance in Solidity docs

> the code from all the base contracts is copied into the created contract.

may produce undesirable behaviors.
For clarification, let me perform the copy process for the example code above:

```
contract C { 
    function test() public {  } 
}

contract B is C {
    function bbb() public {  }
    function test() public {
       bbb(); 
       super.test(); 
    }
} 

contract A is B {
    function bbb() public {  }
    function test() public {
       bbb(); 
       super.test(); 
    }
}
```

Again, if we deploy `A` and calls `A.test()`, then we have a call sequence of `bbb() -> B.test() -> bbb() -> C.test()`, where the `super`s in `A` and `B` are replaced by `B` and `C`, respectively.

Do I have any missing point?

Comment: A.test() -> A.bbb() -> B.test() -> B.bbb() -> C.test(); You can test it out by emitting events in each of them and running in remix.

Comment: @MickySocaci *Before* performing the copy, we only have a sequence of ```bbb -> C.test()```. You may have tested the code after copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance will not "copy" inherited methods instead once a contract is compiled there will be a single contract containing all methods from the base contracts.

For example if we start with

```
contract C { 
    function test() public { log0(0x1111); } 
}

contract B is C {
    function bbb() public { log0(0xbbbb); }
    function test() public {
       bbb(); 
       super.test(); 
    }
} 

contract A is B {
}
```

The compiled contract will look like

```
contract A_compiled {
    function test_internal() private { log0(0x1111); } 
    function bbb() public { log0(0xbbbb); }
    function test() public {
       bbb(); 
       test_internal(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about the mechanical process of how the ```super.test``` in ```B``` is changed into ```test_internal``` ? Did you refer to any documentation? I really want to know the exact mechanism, but I was not able to find relevant materials.

Comment: @SunbeomSo You have to understand that in Solidy inheritance is resolved at compile time. The result of compilation is a single bytecode. All contracts are merged together, to resolve which methods will appears it uses [C3 linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

Comment: Yes I know, but my curious point was that the process of "how they are merged". For example, the contracts should not be merged in a way that I described in my original question. Instead, the contracts should be merged in a way that you examplified. But what is the exact process of merging? (e.g., how is ```super.test``` in ```B``` converted into ```test_internal``` before merged into ```A```?

Comment: @SunbeomSo Sorry, but I can't help you there. The specifics are in the solidity compiler source code, that I'm not familiar with.